# Rear tire burping on gravel bike (tubeless)

Tags: tire, tubeless, gravel, sealant

On my morning commute I burped my rear tire twice having never had that issue before. The rim is a wtb i23 (taped from factory and rate "tubeless ready") and it has a Wtb Riddler tire mounted (also "tubeless ready"). I've had the tubeless setup a bit less than a year with no issues to date, though I haven't ridden the bike in a few weeks. With my laptop etc I was a bit heavier than usual but I've never run into this before on my gravel bike.

First time I was going up a curb and turning (resulting in a sharp off-camber situation). The second time was similar (also a sharp turn) but I didn't lose as much air. The valve is fine so I assume it was a true burp (air out of tire bead).

Is this just a case of not running enough pressure?

I'll top up my tubeless sealant tonight, check the bead and the trueness of the wheel (just trued it, but who knows).

Comment: Burping is normally because the tyre isn't seated on the rim quite right.  Maybe there is damage to either the rim or type bead?

Comment: My experience with mtb is too much sidewall deflection and too low pressure. I'm going to do my best to narrow down the variables tonight. I did have a fairly loose spoke last time I trued the wheel.

Comment: I should point out that if you search for "WTB i23", there are two other recent instances of tubeless problems. Treat as multiple anecdotes, but you have to start to wonder.

Comment: @WeiwenNg thanks! There are plenty of examples. The first one I read was very similar to my experience. Not all tubeless rims are created equal.

Comment: What air pressures were you riding on?  What are the dimensions of your tyre ?

Answer (score 2):

I have a potential answer as the tire is currently holding air and has survived faster speeds and more bumps for quite a few rides since my episode of multiple tire burps.

My pressure was too low on the initial ride and I suspect when it burped it unseated. Pumping up with a mini-pump to proper pressure wasn't enough to properly reseat the tire. When I took the bike home I used the compressor and pumped it up like when I'm seating a tubeless tire then let out air to a proper psi. I didn't get a pop like when initially seating a tubless tire, but it appears to have solved the issue. No slow leak and no more burps.

I am running a bit more pressure than a normally do out of caution, but I'll slowly lower it down to my preferred pressure and update if I run into issues. As pointed out by Weiwen, it may be an issue that the particular rim (WTB i23) doesn't do as good a job holding onto a tubeless bead at low pressures compared to some other rims.

Comment: Can you say roughly what pressures were involved?